# Getting NotSerializableException when trying to write object

Tags: java, serialization

Trying to serialize and send `Lot` object to socket. Getting error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.server.ClientServiceThread
```

Why?

```
public class ClientServiceThread extends Thread  {... // form here called sendObj ...}

public class FlattenLot {
public void sendObj(){
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(oStream);
            out.writeObject(lot); // error
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Lot class:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Lot implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ArrayList<ClientServiceThread> clientBidsLog = new ArrayList<ClientServiceThread>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> bidLog = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private List<Integer> bids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<ClientServiceThread> clients = new ArrayList<ClientServiceThread>();

    private  String NAME;
    private  int INITIAL_PRICE;

    private int MAX_BID = 0;
    public volatile boolean notAvailable = false;
Lot(String name, int initPrice){
        NAME = name;
        INITIAL_PRICE = initPrice;
    }
public synchronized String getName(){return NAME;}
public synchronized int getInitPrice(){return INITIAL_PRICE;}
public synchronized void subscribe(ClientServiceThread t){
        clients.add(t);
      }
public synchronized void unsubscribe(ClientServiceThread t){
        clients.remove(t);
      }
public  synchronized boolean makeBid(ClientServiceThread t,int i){
          if(i > INITIAL_PRICE && i > MAX_BID){
                clientBidsLog.add(t);
                bidLog.add(i);
                bids.add(i);
                MAX_BID = i;
                t.LAST_BID = i;
                notifyAllSubscribers("New bid: "+this.getMaxBid()+" made by "+this.clientBidsLog.get(this.clientBidsLog.size()-1).CLIENT_NAME);
                return true;
          }else{
                return false;
          }


          }
public synchronized void notifyAllSubscribers(String msg){
        for (ClientServiceThread client : clients){
              client.lotUpdated(this, msg);
            }
    }
public synchronized int getMaxBid(){return MAX_BID;}

    private Date time;

    public Lot() {
        time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    }
```

Comment: why would you need to serialize a Thread?

Comment: I serialize *Lot* object. The writeObject method called from Thread which sends data to client.

Comment: The error says that your `ClientServiceThread` can't be serialized. Maybe if you post the code where the error arises people community you could have better help.

Comment: Does Lot implements Serializable?

Comment: Is `Lot` a non-static inner class of `ClientServiceThread`?

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov, Yes, it does

Comment: @ infgeoax, No, `ClientServiceThread` is just a thread binded to socket connection (server <>client). `Lot` is stand alone class

Comment: I'll suggest you to redesign your application (if you can). You are trying to serialize the class that holds all your Threads (maybe you just need the data inside `Lot`, not the Threads in it). In case you can't modify that class, just make your `ClientServiceThread` implements serializable too, or mark your `List<ClientServiceThread> clients` and `public ArrayList<ClientServiceThread> clientBidsLog` as `transient`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Lot` contains

```
public ArrayList<ClientServiceThread> clientBidsLog 
private List<ClientServiceThread> clients
```

If you wish this field to be serialized mark the `ClientServiceThread` `serializable` too

if you don't want it to be serialized just mark it `transient` like

```
public transient ArrayList<ClientServiceThread> clientBidsLog 
private transient List<ClientServiceThread> clients
```

Comment: Or mark that field as `transient` to not include it in serialization.

Comment: Don't forget the `private List<ClientServiceThread> clients` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

The error is caused by trying to serialize a `ClientServiceThread`, which is not serializable. Somehow one of those is part of a `Lot`. If `Lot` is not declared with a `ClientServiceThread` field (or with a field that contains a `ClientServiceThread`), then another possibility is that `Lot` is a non-static inner class of a class that does have such a field. The outer class instance would then be a (hidden) member of `Lot`.

The solution is to either make `ClientServiceThread` serializable (not likely, from its name) or else eliminate it from the serialization by marking the relevant field(s) `transient` (or removing them from the `Lot` class).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of answers have suggested that you could declare `ClientServiceThread` serializable as a possible solution.

WARNING - that probably won't work!

Yes, you can declare a `Thread` subclass that implements `Serializable`, but the Java serialization mechanism can't serialize the stack of a live thread.  In fact, I don't even think it will succeed in serializing an inactive thread's state (e.g. the thread's `ThreadGroup` reference), so you'll probably end up the more exceptions.

I think your only option is to exclude the threads from serialization by declaring those collections to be `transient`.