# ObjectOutputStream ioexception on writeObject with ArrayList of objects

Tags: java

Thanks in advance for any reply.
Im trying to save an ArrayList of objects to file, but keep getting IOExeption.
The code :

```
public static final String FILE_PATH=""; // is set to blank for tests. It DOES create a file.

public static void saveToFileCl(ArrayList<cliente> al ) {
    if (al != null ) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream  file = new FileOutputStream(FILE_PATH+"cliente.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
            outStream.writeInt(cliente.getAuto_inc()); // works fine
            outStream.writeObject(new Date()); // works fine - not needed just for testing!
            outStream.writeObject(al); // exception !!!!
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("Erro a gravar ficheiro de clientes!\n"+e.getCause());}
          catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Erro a desconhecido ao gravar ficheiro de clientes!\n"+e.getMessage());}
    }    
}
```

Does any one can tell me why the exception?

Comment: please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Full error stack trace please

Comment: Is `cliente` serializable ? Something tell me the stacktrace tell you exactly the same think...

Comment: No, it is not serializable. Mainely because i dint know it has to be. What is it and where do i get more info about that?

Comment: Print the Stacktrace in the catch IOException ... `e.printStackTrace();` But if it is not serializable, simply add `implements Serializable` to the class `cliente` to correct this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting NotSerializableException when trying to write object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907838/getting-notserializableexception-when-trying-to-write-object)

Comment: So, i was just checkin and found this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm[link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) . So i just need to add implements java.io.Serializable to the class header?

Comment: That's what I said, yes. Follow the tutorial.

Comment: Working now. It needed to be serialized.From all the examples i got from searching on how to save an ArrayList of objects, none  was talking about that, but i realized now that its quite basic stuf. Thanks to all that reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write an instance into an OutputStream with `OutputStream.writeObject(Object)` you need the instance to be `Serializable`. This is that interface  (java.io.Serializable) that tell that an instance can be store in a byte form.

You just need to add the interface to the class

```
class MyClass implements java.io.Serializable { ... }
```

There is no methods to implements, just this line is enough.